# Filter view behaviour when filtered list changes

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet which summarises work for staff, and a filter view for each staff member so they can quickly see what they need to do. This works well.

However, if a new person is added to the staff list, every filter view now **includes** that new person's tasks as well.

How can I prevent this to avoid having to update every filter view each time a new staff member is added?

Answer (score 0):

The solution (which occurred to me while typing the question) is to create the filter using a condition (eg "text starts with FirstName").

Answer (score 0):

you could use regular formula instead:

```
=QUERY(A:Z; "where A = 'FirstName'")
```

or if you wana play with "start with":

```
=QUERY(A:Z; "where A starts with 'FirstName'")
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. I've used QUERY elsewhere, but a specific (unstated above) requirement is for multiple people to use the sheet at the same time, so a FILTER VIEW was felt to be the best option.

Thanks for your input though.